# Is it possible to launch a process under powershell and have visual studio immediately connect to it for debugging

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, debugging

I have a program foo.exe

```
foo.exe  sometxtfile -arg0 10 -arg1 "cats" -arg3 666
```

It currently crashes with an exception. I have the project in visual studio and could put that command line into the visual studio debug startup but I'd like to be more flexible and be able to start this from powershell.

I am aware of [Debug-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/debug-process?view=powershell-6) but that only debugs a currently running process. Would it be possible to use this to launch and debug?

Comment: I assume you have the sources for `foo.exe`, so can't you just add a command line option (say `-debug`, or env-var or whatever) that causes `foo.exe` itself to call `DebugBreak` or `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` (depending on whether you're native or managed) at the earliest point possible.

Comment: Thankyou. That is a valid solution. However I'd still like to know if I can launch and debug from powershell. It is native code. C++ based

Comment: Well, another option is to use `Gflags` (see [here](https://bugslasher.net/2011/03/26/how-to-debug-a-process-as-soon-as-it-starts-with-windbg-or-visual-studio-2010/) for an example). That would work with any execution of `foo.exe`, regardless how, until changed back YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to wait for the process to start the job as a background process and then call Debug-Process on it.

```
start-job {
    foo.exe  sometxtfile -arg0 10 -arg1 "cats" -arg3 666
}
$process="foo"
Write-Host "Waiting for $process to start" 
Do {

    $status = Get-Process $process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    If (!($status)) { 
        Write-Host -NoNewline '.' 
    }

    Else { 
        Write-Host ""  
        Write-Host "$process has started"  
        $started = $true 
    }

}
Until ( $started )
```

debug-process -Name ${process}

```
debug-process -Name ${process}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)